# How to insert several csv files into Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have several csv files on university courses that all seem linked by an ID, that you can find [here](https://www.hesa.ac.uk/support/tools-and-downloads/unistats), and I wondered how to put them on Elasticsearch. I know, thanks to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imrKm6dV3NQ) and Logstash, how to insert one sole file csv file to Elasticsearch. But do you know how to insert several such as those in the provided link ?

At the moment I started with a first `.config` file for a first csv file : `ACCREDITATION.csv`. But it would be painful to write them all...

The `.config` file is :

```
input{
    file{
        path =>"Users/mike/Data/ACCREDITATION.csv"
        start_position => "begining"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    }
}

filter{
    csv{
        separator => ","
        columns => ['PUBUKPRN', 'UKPRN', 'KISCOURSEID', 'KISMODE', 'ACCTYPE', 'ACCDEPEND', 'ACCDEPENDURL', 'ACCDEPENDURLW']

    }
    mutate{convert => ["PUBUKPRN","integer"]}
    mutate{convert => ["UKPRN","integer"]}
    mutate{convert => ["KISMODE","integer"]}
    mutate{convert => ["ACCTYPE","integer"]}
    mutate{convert => ["ACCDEPEND","integer"]}
}

output{
    elasticsearch{
        hosts =>"localhost"
        index =>"accreditation"
        document_type =>"accreditaiton keys"
    }
    stdout{}
}
```

#### Update May, 3rd

Without knowing how to use a `.config` file to implement csv files to Elasticsearch, I fell back to Elastic blog and tried to do a shell script `importSVFiles` for a first `.csv` file before trying to generalize the approach :

#### importCSVFiles :

```
#!/bin/bash
while read f1
do        
   curl -XPOST 'https://XXX.us-east-1.aws.found.io:9243/courses/accreditation' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -u elastic:XXX -d "{ \"accreditation\": \"$f1\" }"
done < AccreditationByHep.csv
```

Yet I received a `mapper_parsing_exception` on the terminal :

```
mike@mike-thinks:~/Data/on_2018_04_25_16_43_17$ ./importCSVFiles
{"error":{"root_cause":
            [{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse"}],
          "type":"mapper_parsing_exception",
          "reason":"failed to parse",
          "caused_by":{"type":"i_o_exception","reason":"Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 13)): 
              has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.BytesReference$MarkSupportingStreamInputWrapper@e18584; line: 1, column: 88]"}
         },"status":400
}
```

Comment: Could you [add](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/205576/edit) the `.config` definition to your question?

Answer (score 1):

I just had a look at the data in the Higher Education Statistics Agency (HESA) zipped file and the files are all different.

This means you will either have to create an individual `.config` file for each import or create a single `.config` file using conditions as described in the following article:

***Reference:*** [How to use multiple csv files in logstash](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-use-multiple-csv-files-in-logstash/90200) (Elastic Discuss Forum)

Expanding on your first `.config` by one level:

```
input{
    file{
        path =>"Users/mike/Data/ACCREDITATION.csv"
        start_position => "begining"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    }
    file{
        path =>"Users/mike/Data/ACCREDITATION.csv"
        start_position => "begining"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    }

}

filter{
    # added condition for first file
    if [path] == "Users/mike/Data/ACCREDITATION.csv"{
        csv{
            separator => ","
            columns => ['PUBUKPRN', 'UKPRN', 'KISCOURSEID', 'KISMODE', 'ACCTYPE', 'ACCDEPEND', 'ACCDEPENDURL', 'ACCDEPENDURLW']

        }
        mutate{convert => ["PUBUKPRN","integer"]}
        mutate{convert => ["UKPRN","integer"]}
        mutate{convert => ["KISMODE","integer"]}
        mutate{convert => ["ACCTYPE","integer"]}
        mutate{convert => ["ACCDEPEND","integer"]}
    }
    # added condition for second file
    else if [path] == "Users/mike/Data/AccreditationByHep.csv"{
        csv{
            separator => ","
            columns => ['AccreditingBodyName', 'AccreditionType', 'HEP', 'KisCourseTitle', 'KiscourseID']
        }
    # ommitted mutations for second file
    }

}

output{
    # added condition for first file
    if [path] == "Users/mike/Data/ACCREDITATION.csv"{ 
        elasticsearch{
            hosts =>"localhost"
            index =>"accreditation"
            document_type =>"accreditaiton keys"
        }
    }
    # added condition for second file
    else if [path] == "Users/mike/Data/AccreditationByHep.csv"{
        elasticsearch{
            hosts =>"localhost"
            index =>"accreditationByHep"
            document_type =>"accreditaitonbyhep keys"
        }
    }
    stdout{}
}
```

<sub>[`document_type`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.2/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-document_type) is a deprecated configuration option</sub>

You should be able to expand on this example on your own.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I'm now watching [getting Started with Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/webinars/getting-started-logstash) to know how to concretely send my data with this `.config` file

Comment: I've just watching the video I provided above to see how they import files but they use Filebeat and run a `filebeat.yml` file to store logs which is a too different approach from mine. How do you use the `.config` file to store the data ?